# NET CF - Application Closes when hiding a modal form

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I recently created a simple custom message-box. Its just another form called using ShowDialog().

I have two buttons YES / NO that sets the DialogResult value then Hides the form using this.Hide().

However, when I do this, the entire application closes. This does not happen when using this.Close(). The reason why I chose using Hide is because the response appears to be faster. When using Close, the Message Box Form lingers for 2-3 seconds before closing.

Below is some code:

```
    public static void Init()
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            _instance = new MQMessageBox();
            _instance.MQButtonYes.Click += MQButtonYes_Click;
            _instance.MQButtonNo.Click  += MQButtonNo_Click;
        }
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string caption, string message)
    {
        Init();

        _instance.Caption = caption;
        _instance.Message = message;

        DialogResult result = _instance.ShowDialog();

        return result;
    }

    private void MQButtonYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void MQButtonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

From the main form, its being called as:

```
    MQMessageBox.Show("Warning", "Hello World");
    this.Show(); //Adding this call, will show the main form again. Without this call, the mobile will show the Today Screen making it appear the app has crashed.
```

Main method is:

```
        MQMainForm mainForm = new MQMainForm();
        Application.Run(mainForm);
```

Comment: Setting the DialogResult closes the Form.  My bet is that the subsequent call to Hide is causing problems.  What happens if you remove those calls?

Comment: Can you show your application's Main method? (Where you call Application.Run(...))

Comment: Hi Alan, edited the post to include the main method

Comment: Hi Chris, setting the DialogResult closes out the form as mentioned  However, I did find that the application is not actually getting closed. It gets minimized instead. It appears the forms are "toggling" to some effect

Comment: When you use `ShowDialog` you create modal dialog.  That dialog no controls the focus of the application--it's the only dialog that processes input.  If you "hide" it, what would you expect your application to be able to do at that point?

Comment: Well since i have a main form, the expectation is for the modal form to return focus and control to the main form to proceed handling the users response.

Comment: Are you calling `MQMessageBox.Show` in the Main form load or in response to button click or other event?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not what you want to hear, but calling the following code is not really valid:

```
private void MQButtonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
    this.Hide();
}
```

The reason for this is that setting `DialogResult` is not the same as calling `Form.Close()`. I examined the implementation of Form in both the Compact Framework and the regular Framework in Reflector. Unfortunately I was not able to see the exact implementation of Form in the Compact Framework, but I was able to look into the regular implementation which should be similar.

The implementation of Close sets a flag that the Form is to be closed and then sends WM_CLOSE to the window. Setting `DialogResult` only sets a private variable in the Form. Now, I know what you are thinking, "but, I know that setting `DialogResult` closes the form! everyone knows that!". The key to understanding this behavior is how this happens. When you call `Form.ShowDialog()` it creates a new window message loop for the modal form. This creates a loop which processes window messages. The termination condition for this loop involves checking whether the user called Close() from the boolean that was set during close and/or whether `DialogResult` is set. Therefore, setting `DialogResult` will cause the message loop to terminate and close the Form.

From what I can tell, the problem with Hiding the Form is that you are setting `DialogResult`, but then when you hide the form, I believe that the Window is no longer receiving Window messages. Therefore, the message loop is probably waiting for the next message before checking the `DialogResult`'s value.

You could experiment with this by getting a handle to the Form and sending it WM_CLOSE, but I'd imagine that going around the intended method of closing the Form to shave a few seconds of how long it takes, is probably not worth the cost of the probably unknown behavior of such a hack.